# How can I get top one record from foriegn key table along with each primary key table record?

Tags: sql

I have two tables **Forum** and **ForumCateory**.
ForumCateoryId is the mapping field.

The `Forum` table contains the fields such as:

```
ForumId, Title,Description and ForumCategoryId
```

The `ForumCategory` table contains 
`ForumCategoryId,ForumCategory`

I need to display all records from **ForumCategory** and **top 1 Title and Description From Forum.**

Comment: "Top 1 title and description from forum" will it have the same ForumCategoryId with ForumCategory?

Comment: Yes.There is a one to many relation between ForumCategory and Forum .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ti use `top 1` in subquery

```
select  *
from ForumCategory FC
join (select top 1 ForumId, Title,Description, ForumCategoryId
      from Forum 
      where F.ForumCategoryId = FC.ForumCategoryId 
     ) F
```

or try to use `aggregate function` (`min` for example) in subquery:

```
select  *
from ForumCategory FC
join Forum F on  F.ForumCategoryId = FC.ForumCategoryId
             and F.ForumId = ( select min(F2.ForumId)
                               from Forum F2
                               where F2.ForumCategoryId = F.ForumCategoryId        
                              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need last Forum for each Forum Category, so i ordered forum by ForumId descending.

```
select
    FC.ForumCategoryId,
    FC.ForumCategory,
    F.Title as ForumTitle,
    F.Description as ForumDescription
from ForumCategory as FC
    outer apply
    (
        select top 1 TT.*
        from Forum as TT
        where TT.ForumCategoryId = FC.ForumCategoryId
        order by TT.ForumId desc
    ) as F
```

you can also try something like this

```
select top 1 with ties
    FC.ForumCategoryId,
    FC.ForumCategory,
    F.Title as ForumTitle,
    F.Description as ForumDescription
from @ForumCategory as FC
    left outer join @Forum as F on F.ForumCategoryId = FC.ForumCategoryId
order by
    row_number() over (partition by FC.ForumCategoryId order by F.ForumId desc)
```